# on click of outlook send button should be able to connect to dynamic CRM and stored data

Tags: dynamics-crm, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-restapi

As the new meeting is created , all the meeting details like subject, organizer and start time of meeting all these details I want to store into the Dynamic CRM table on click of the outlook(app) send button.

I have followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/smart-alerts-onmessagesend-walkthrough?tabs=xmlmanifest) and created one launcevent.js file and on onAppointmentSendHandler function write code for connecting to CRM and store the subject and organizer into tables, also used the Office.actions.associate but still when create new meeting on click of the send button I am getting your add-in is not available try after some time, also I have used the send mode property as 'Prompt User' I am also confused where I should use onAppointmentSendHandler or onItemSendHandler. any help on this will be really appreciated as I am struggling on this for a long time. also here I am attaching the link of git hub code where my code is stored. [github](https://github.com/Ukhan11/OutlookAddinforcrm)          Any help or guidance on this issue would be greatly appreciated. I have run this code but when I clicked on send button it shows add-in is taking longer than expected.

Comment: Is this effectively a duplicate of this other post from you?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75723294/not-able-to-connect-to-dynamic-crm-on-click-of-out-look-send-button